# llamar clave foranea con dato BIGINT

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo un problema al hacer referencia a una tabla, en la tabla "Pendientes" quiero mostrar un archivo subido por un usuario y este contenido se muestra en el mismo, el parametro del identficador de archivo es "bigint" el cual muestra un procedimiento para cuando se suba un documento este lo muestre en string y lo convierta a numero. pero al ponerlo como llave foranea, porque este valor es invalido, hay alguna forma de referenciarlo?

```
create table Pendientes
(
IdP int identity(1,1) primary key not null,
EstadoP nvarchar(2) not null,
IdR int foreign key references Registro(IdR),  
-->
kArchivo bigint foreign key references Archivos(kArchivo)
-->
-->Id, Usuario, Asunto, Fecha, Archivo, status aprovacion
)


create table Archivos
(
kArchivo bigint identity(1,1) primary key not null,
Imagen image null,
Archivo varchar (250)
)
go
```

Comment: No se entiende el problema que tienes. ¿Cuál es el error? ¿Cuál es el procedimiento que te da problemas?

Answer (score 0):

A lo que entiendo o no se si estoy mal pero a lo que estoy viendo en tu  código es que hay un error de sintaxis ya que primero tienes que crear la tabla principal (**archivos**) y después la tabla que va a llevar la clave foránea, y quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
create table Archivos
(
kArchivo bigint identity(1,1) primary key not null,
Imagen image null,
Archivo varchar (250)
)

create table Pendientes
(
IdP int identity(1,1) primary key not null,
EstadoP nvarchar(2) not null,
IdR int, foreign key (IdR) references Registro(IdR),  
-->
kArchivo bigint, foreign key (kArchivo) references Archivos(kArchivo)
-->
-->Id, Usuario, Asunto, Fecha, Archivo, status aprovacion
)
go
```

**Una cosa mas, trata de poner una coma antes de hacer tu clave foránea.**